how to pass remaining options to the native tool by cmakelists?
I'm learning c and using cmake and ninja to build program,i find that i can't see what arguments been used in gcc even i add the set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILEON ON) in the cmakelists.txt
i had already figure out i can do this by add -v at the end cmake build command to pass the argument to ninja just like this:
cmake --build /temp/build --config Debug --target all -- -v
but i want to do this by click the build button of cmake plugin in vscode rather than typing command
is there any soluton?

well i solved it by myself(
i need to add following code in CMakeLists.txt

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "ON" FORCE)

but i still not understand why i have to add the CACHE BOOL "ON" and FORCE

Actually, I think you don't need to change your listfile (CMakeLists.txt) to make ninja output more verbose. You can switch over to your build directory and say something like: ninja -v or ninja -v <your-target> <another-target>.
But if you do need, you have to do with the set command for a cached entry and put the FORCE option, because, at first, CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE is initialized as a cached entry by the project command, see here, and you can't change any existed cached entry without the FORCE option.
